# Invoke method with an Object List

Tags: java, methods, invoke

This code allow me invoking a method with tests parameter

```
Method m = aClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
Integer n =10;
Object retobj =m.invoke(o, "test",n);
System.out.println(retobj);
```

Now I want to invoke the method with the arguments list.

```
List<Object> arguments =container.getArgs();
Object retobj =m.invoke(o, (Object) arguments);
```

But I get this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Comment: What is the signature of the the method you are invoking?

Comment: Spend some time in reading [Oracle Tutorial -Invoking Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`invoke` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) takes two parameters: the object on which to invoke the method, and a "varargs" parameter to hold the arguments.

Such a parameter (also "variable arity") is interchangeable with an array, and it's treated as an array in the body of such a method.

Convert your `List<Object>` to an array, then pass it in.

```
Object retobj = m.invoke(o, arguments.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `invoke` call, you are passing 2 arguments, in the second `invoke`, you are only passing 1.